# ERROR: could not find gem engineyard-serverside locally or in a repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, engineyard

I am new to Engine Yard.

I just clone an app from the github , its already live at engine yard server.

Now when i try to push latest changes using `ey deploy --ref production` command it do gave me the error.

```
ERROR:  could not find gem engineyard-serverside locally or in a repository
/usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: engineyard-serverside(1.4.1 not = 1.4.10) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/ey_resin/ruby/bin/engineyard-serverside:18
Failed deployment recorded in AppCloud
Deploy failed
```

Is there any one who can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the engineyard gem do you have on your local machine? It could be an issue with a specific version of that gem that was recently patched; upgrade to engineyard version 1.3.30 on your local machine and try again.  That should hopefully alleviate the problem.  Otherwise you can submit a ticket to Engine Yard's support staff at support.engineyard.com.